# variable_scope does not get reused when using default scope name

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a question regarding sub-scopes when reusing variables. This

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_bar():
  with tf.variable_scope('bar'):
    tf.get_variable('baz', ()) 

with tf.variable_scope('foo') as scope:
  make_bar()
  scope.reuse_variables()
  make_bar()
```

works perfectly fine, only a single variable `foo/bar/baz` is created.

However, if I change `make_bar` to

```
def make_bar(scope=None):
  with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'bar'):
    tf.get_variable('baz', ())
```

the code now fails with a

```
ValueError: Variable foo/bar_1/baz does not exist
```

Question: why does variable scope reuse fail when using `default name`s? If it is on purpose, what is the rationale behind this choice?

**EDIT**

Some precisions on the `default_name` argument of `tf.variable_scope`. [From the documentation,](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope#__init__)

> - `default_name`: The default name to use if the `name_or_scope` argument is `None`, this name will be uniquified. If `name_or_scope` is provided it won't be used and therefore it is not required and can be `None`.

So as it name underlies, it is a way to provide a default scope name.

In the first version of `make_bar`, the scope name is forced to be `bar` -- the function has no parameter to change it.

In the second version of `make_bar`, I enhance this function to make it parameterizable. So `bar` is still the default scope name (provided this time as the `default_name` argument of `tf.variable_scope`), but this time the caller has the possibility to change it by setting the default argument `scope` of `make_bar` to anything else than `None`.`

When this second version of `make_bar` is used without an argument, it should, I think, fall back to the behavior of the first version -- which it does not.

Note that in my example, `bar` is intended to be a subscope of `foo`. The variable to be reused is *meant* to be `foo/bar/baz`.

Comment: When you change `make_bar()` to `make_bar(scope=None)` are you also changing the `make_bar()` function calls to match this?

Comment: No I am not -- the calling code stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope

> If `name_or_scope` is not None, it is used as is. If `name_or_scope`
>   is None, then `default_name` is used. In that case, if the same name
>   has been previously used in the same scope, it will be made **unique**
>   by appending `_N` to it.

...

> To prevent accidental sharing of variables, we raise an exception when
>   getting an existing variable in a non-reusing scope.

...

> Similarly, we raise an exception when trying to get a variable that
>   does not exist in reuse mode.

By using `None` scope you are forcing each call to `get_variable` to generate unique scope/variable, but by calling `reuse_variables` you are forcing subsequent calls to only return existing variables. There is no variable to return so `ValueError` is raised. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: So what is the rationale behind this choice, why should a default name never be reused?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯, I never used this library, just browsed the docs for you

Comment: I guess it sometimes makes sense to be able to create temporary scope for single use, do some work in it and throw it away (or make sure it is not reused by making it unique), that's when you would use `default_name`. I think the name `default_name` is misleading though, it's more like 'temporary scope basename'

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually using the scope 'foo' in your example. You need to pass the parameter to `tf.variable_scope('foo', 'bar')` or `tf.variable_scope(scope, 'bar')`.
you're calling the method `make_bar` without the parameter in either case, which means in your first example `name_or_scope='bar'`, in the second example `name_or_scope=scope` (with value `None`) and `default_name='bar'`.

this is probably what you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_bar(scope=None):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'bar'):
        tf.get_variable('baz', ())

with tf.variable_scope('foo') as scope:
    make_bar(scope)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    make_bar(scope)
```

I would actually advise against using default parameters because they reduce readability like in your example. When is a `None` scope ever the answer you want? it would make more sense if you test it, maybe like this?

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_bar(scope=None):
    if scope is None:
        scope = 'default_scope'
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'bar'):
        tf.get_variable('baz', ())


with tf.variable_scope('foo') as scope:
    make_bar(scope)   # use foo scope
    scope.reuse_variables()
    make_bar()        # use 'default_scope'
```

but this makes code less readable and more likely to lead to bugs

Comment: Absolutely not. My question is precisely on using the `default_name` argument of `variable_scope`. If I provide explicitely a scope argument to `make_bar`, then the default name argument is not used -- that's off the point.

Comment: When you call a function that has a default value for an argument without providing an explicit argument, it will use that default value. By calling `make_bar()` with no explicit argument, you are calling `with variable_scope(scope, 'bar')` as `with variable_scope(None, 'bar')`. Milo is correct

Comment: When the `scope` argument is `None` then the `default_scope` argument of `variable_scope` is used. If scope is anything else than `None` then `'bar'` is simply not used.

Comment: Also I think you did not understand that `bar` is supposed to be a subscope of `foo` -- there is no choosing between `foo` and `bar`. The expected result is to reuse the variable `foo/bar/baz`, as mentionned in my question.

Comment: ok, the default parameter of make_bar seems to be a distraction. see my other answer.